# execute war file using exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I package my spring boot application as a .war file. Then use the

> java -jar MyProj-{version}.war

to run it from command prompt.

No I am trying to execute the same command using 'exec-maven-plugin'. But it is failing with the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on
>   project MyProj: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid
>   -> [Help 1]

I dint provide the main class as I am not providing in command prompt. Following is my plugin. I use command

> exec:java

to run it from eclipse.

**Plugin**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-jar</argument>
                                <argument>${basedir}/target/MyProj-${project.version}.war</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Hm.. `mvn spring-boot:run` is not an option?

Comment: It is starting the application. But somehow the mapping is not happening.
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Is it starting the same .war file?

Comment: Have you tested if this works correctly simply via `java -jar ....war`?

Comment: yes in command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<executable>java</executable>
```

into your `<configuration>` and move `<configuration>...</configuration>` outside of `<executions/>`.

Comment: I added it as <configuration>
       <executable>java</executable>
       <arguments>, same error results

Comment: just noticed that your `configuration` is a child of `execution` while it should be a child of `plugin`

Comment: <plugin>
    <configuration>
     <executable>java</executable>
    </configuration>
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project MetricsUI: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: i did exec:java